# Code not working on specific version of IE9

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas

I have drawing application where users are allowed to draw various shapes on canvas. Code is tested and working properly on Chrome,IE 10,IE 9(9.0.8112.16421), however it's showing absurd behavior on IE 9(9.0.8112.16421 64-bit edition).The main issue is images are not getting drawn on canvas(sometime). Unable to figure out the reason, if i start debugging or put alerts between loading images and drawing them on canvas then it works properly.Seems like images are not getting loaded fully but if that's the reason then it should behave similar in IE 9 version which is not 64-bit edition. Any clue how to handle this problem???

Answer (score 0):

Clues:

The app misbehaves intermittently by not showing images that should appear.

The app draws properly if:

- start loading images
- alert box
- resume app after dismissing alert box

Sounds like you're not giving your images time to load before trying to drawImage them.

```
// This doesn't guarantee image1 is fully loaded before trying to use it

var image1=new Image();
image1.src="myImage.png";
context.drawImage(image1,0,0);
```

The fix is to use the image's .onload callback which is triggered when that image is fully loaded

```
// This guaranteed image1 is fully loaded before trying to use it

var image1=new Image();
image1.onload=function(){
    context.drawImage(image1,0,0);
}
image1.src="myImage.png";
```

If you have many images to load, here is a an image loader that loads all images and then calls start():

```
var imagesOK=0;
var imgs=[];
var imageURLs=[];
// .push all your image urls into imageURLs[]
// imageURLs.push("myImage1.png"); 
// imageURLs.push("myImage2.png");  
imageURLs.push("");
loadAllImages(start);

function loadAllImages(callback){
    for (var i=0; i<imageURLs.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        imgs.push(img);
        img.onload = function(){ 
            imagesOK++; 
            if (imagesOK>=imageURLs.length ) {
                callback();
            }
        };
        img.onerror=function(){alert("image load failed");} 
        img.crossOrigin="anonymous";
        img.src = imageURLs[i];
    }      
}

function start(){

    // the imgs[] array holds fully loaded images
    // the imgs[] are in the same order as imageURLs[]

}
```